# Hammer.js stops working after a while

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, hammer.js

I'm having this strange issue, where I'm using hammer.js library to create some responsive table functionalities.

When I'm testing the page on my iPhone (this issue is not happening on any Android device, iPhone only), the functionality works fine if I'm testing it from my local machine - I'm using [Ghostlab](http://vanamco.com/ghostlab/) for testing pages from local machine. However, when I deploy the code to staging server, functionality breaks. What I mean by breaks is that it works fine, but it stops working after 2 pan events (pan event is hammer.js event). This issue is both on Chrome and Safair on iPhone.

I also opened Safari console to my phone and I'm not getting any JS errors. And I tried copying local .js file to staging server and that didn't solve the issue either.

Does anyone have an idea, why the same code isn't working on staging server but it does on local server?

Comment: Any insight about this?

Comment: I solved this issue by initializing hammer object on one of the parent elements. Basically I didn't change any of the code except for the selector and the issue was gone.

Comment: Hmmm... not helping much with the issue I am facing, but thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because the element that contains the pan event is moved off screen.

So instead of adding the callback functions on pan to set the `left` css value on `.gallery-inner` like the following:

```
<script>
var startPos = 0;
var scrollContainer = document.getElementById('scrollable');
var hammertime = new Hammer(scrollContainer);

hammertime.on('panend', function(ev) {
  startPos = parseInt(scrollContainer.style.left.replace('px', ''));
});

hammertime.on('pan', function(ev) {
  var pos = parseInt(startPos) + ev.deltaX;
  scrollContainer.style.left = pos + 'px';
});
</script>

<style>
.gallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.gallery-inner {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}
.gallery-inner > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>

<div class="gallery">
  <div id="scrollable" class="gallery-inner">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add another container for the touch area, and set the `left` value on it.

eg.

```
<script>
  var startPos = 0;
var hammerContainer = document.getElementById('hammer');
var scrollContainer = document.getElementById('scrollable');
var hammertime = new Hammer(hammerContainer);

hammertime.on('panend', function(ev) {
  startPos = parseInt(scrollContainer.style.left.replace('px', ''));
});

hammertime.on('pan', function(ev) {
  var pos = parseInt(startPos) + ev.deltaX;
  scrollContainer.style.left = pos + 'px';
});
</script>

<style>
.gallery {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.gallery-scrollable {
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: visible;
}
.gallery-scrollable > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>

<div class="gallery">
  <div id="hammer" class="gallery-inner">
    <div id="scrollable" class="gallery-scrollable">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>11</div>
      <div>12</div>
      <div>13</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code sample here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbgLzz